# Windbg - Unknown exception code with weird input parameters

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have a crash dump to analyze which was taken, allegedly, from a hung system. After running !alanyze -v I get this output from windbg:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Unknown bugcheck code (0)
Unknown bugcheck description
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on MALCOLMMLOCA62C

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 2

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 116

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject


BUGCHECK_CODE:  0

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  System

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x45474150 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  45474150

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  4547415045474150

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  4547415045474150

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  4547415045474150

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER4: 4547415045474150

BAD_STACK_POINTER:  ffffbc0f13c29900

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffbc0f`13c29900 fffff805`1967de62 : ffffd28f`9163f108 ffffbc0f`13c29a40 ffffe600`491a0180 ffffd28f`9163f010 : nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1d
ffffbc0f`13c29940 fffff805`1967da23 : 00000000`00000000 ffffbc0f`13c29c00 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0x38a
ffffbc0f`13c29b00 fffff805`197a1424 : 00000000`00000000 ffffe600`491a0180 ffffe600`491ab0c0 ffffd28f`950020c0 : nt!PoIdle+0x1b3
ffffbc0f`13c29c60 00000000`00000000 : ffffbc0f`13c2a000 ffffbc0f`13c24000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x54


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+1d

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  1d

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x0_STACKPTR_ERROR_nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {94784d45-ed21-c95f-fc42-87fec626bbee}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

On the first examination you can see that error code 45474150 has no correlating entry in NTSTATUS and weirdly all 4 arguments are all just a duplicated over to next 4 bytes value of an exception code, which is suspicious.

Also, if I run .exr -1 I get this:

```
0: kd> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 4547415045474150
   ExceptionCode: 45474150
  ExceptionFlags: 45474150
NumberParameters: 1162297680
   Parameter[0]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[1]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[2]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[3]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[4]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[5]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[6]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[7]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[8]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[9]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[10]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[11]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[12]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[13]: 4547415045474150
   Parameter[14]: 4547415045474150
```

I'm not at all well versed in windows internals and debugging so I'm pretty lost here. Can anyone suggest a debugging pattern for this kind of behavior?

Comment: Looking for exceptions in a deadlocked program doesn't make sense.  Find out what the threads are doing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323635/how-to-examine-user-thread-call-stack-from-windbg-kernel-debugger

Comment: you are looking at some un mapped memory the dump is corrupt most probably >>> split = [chr(int("0x"+magic[j:j+2],16)) for j in range(0,len(magic),2)]
>>> split,magic
(['E', 'G', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'G', 'A', 'P'], '4547415045474150')

Comment: @HansPassant, Oh, ok, I'll try that, thanks a lot!

Comment: @blabb,  according to people, who collected this dump, it shouldn't be corrupt, but still thanks. But I'm having trouble understanding what this python script should do and what 'magic' actually us

Comment: the pattern yousee 45474150 indicates PAGE (little endian ) that is what the python script shows magic is a label to this string  PAGE is a filler used by dbgeng dumpwriter since allyour data is having that filler it could be corrupt C:\>e:\GIT\usr\bin\xxd.exe calc.dmp |grep PAGE
0184d840: 0090 7e00 0043 0100 0050 4147 4500 0000  ..~..C...PAGE...

Comment: @blabb, now I get it, thank you very much, yeah, it's probably corrupt.

Comment: You are probably looking for [!locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-locks---kdext--locks-). That allows you to examine lock cycles that cause a deadlock.

Comment: use dumpchk  to check the dump it provides a bitmore verbose info about the dmp orif youare a bit versed wtih python take a look at my [github pydmpchk](https://github.com/blabberer/pydmpchk) here the whole dump consists of several streams you can dissect them  offline if windbg isnt able to work with it   pingme ifreqd

Comment: @blabb, I think I could make use of pydmpchk. Also, the dump is not corrupt in a sense that it's not malformed and unanalyzable, it's just took from a hung system (not BSOD) therefore the header is filled with PAGE to state exception params as insignificant. Thank you very much for your help, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: ok if it helped i am glad if you improved it or added functionality ill be glad to hear them  or pull them in if you find some bugs or face problems ill be glad as well to see it solved.